# QtQuick: how to connect a tcp client (signal / slot) with the GUI in qml

Tags: server, tcp, qml, qt6

I'm currently writing my first QtQuick application with GUI in qml code that includes a TCP server. The whole thing is already running quite well and several clients can connect to the server from outside on the defined port.
For the server code, I mainly kept the following source:
https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Asynchronous_QTcpServer_QThreadPool.php

In other words, as soon as a client connects from the outside, a new object is created dynamically by the type client and a new socket is opened.

```
void MyServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    // At the incoming connection, make a client
    // and set the socket
    MyClient *client = new MyClient(this);
    client->setSocket(socketDescriptor);
}
```

I am now having trouble connecting a object of type MyClient to my GUI (all in *.qml). The MyClient class is then responsible for processing incoming data.
In my case, in particular, I parse the incoming bytes in the MyClient::readyRead() method and want to trigger the corresponding action / display on the GUI.
Say I would have some emit() calls in the function.
How do I connect these emitting signals to the GUI in a straight way?

Or do I always have to send a signal to the MyServer class first and then it can only pass the signal on to the GUI?
That would be very cumbersome.
I would prefer to directly send the appropriate signals from the MyClient class to the GUI.

I'm kind of stuck here...

So far I have only registered the myServer class in my main.cpp to the Qml Engine.
That's the crux of the matter now.
The QML engine doesn't currently know anything about the dynamically created objects/clients (of type MyClient) inside the myserver class.

My main.cpp looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/main.qml"_qs);

    // add global c++ object to the QML context as a property
    MyServer myServer;
    QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("myServer", &myServer); // the object will be available in QML with name "myServer"


    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    // Create an instance of a server and then start it.
    myServer.StartServer();
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
}
```

How to deal with this problem?
What would an elegant solution look like?

My "workaround" would then actually be to provide many slots on myServer for each signal to be sent from the client and within the slot method to send a signal to the GUI. As I said, super cumbersome and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways it could be done. Let's say your signal is something like `MyClient::dataWasRead()`. You could connect that to MyServer (since MyServer knows about all the different clients), and then MyServer could emit its own signal `MyServer::dataWasRead(int clientIndex)`. The GUI could listen for that signal and know which client the signal came from. You could even provide an accessor function in MyServer so the GUI could directly access the clients if needed. (Something like `MyServer::getClient(clientIndex)`.) Depends on the needs of your app.

Comment: Or create a property of type `QList<MyClient*>` directly (since `getClient` would not get updated when the client is deleted and result in a dangling pointer)

Comment: Yep, that's another way to go. My answer does not necessarily result in a dangling pointer, but it does leave that possibility open.